# Python import package doesn't working when running python code using IronPython DLR Hosting API

Tags: c#, ironpython

I have searched StackOverflow but didn't found a solution for my problem. 
I'm using Iron Python 2.7.3 DLR Hosting API.
What i'm trying to do is invoke python functions of pure python script from C# code. I took example from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seshadripv/archive/2008/06/30/how-to-invoke-a-python-function-from-c-using-the-dlr-hosting-api.aspx) and this simple code is working as a charm.
But my use case is little more complex and in my python module i'm doing imports of non standard packages and modules.

MyModule.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7")
sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib")
sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\lib2to3")

import os
import clr

sys.path.append(r'C:\MyPythonCodeLocation')
# mypackage are located at C:\MyPythonCodeLocation
import mypackage

def foo(p):
    print '{0}: module - {1}, package - {2}'.format(p,__name__,__package__);
```

Then i calling foo function from c# like this

```
var pyRuntime = Python.CreateRuntime();
ScriptEngine pyEng = pyRuntime.GetEngine("python");
ScriptSource source = pyEng.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("MyModule.py");
ScriptScope scope = pyEng.CreateScope();
source.Execute(scope);               
Func<int, bool> f = bis.GetVariable<Func<int, bool>>("foo");
f(1);
```

But `Source.Execute(scope);` throws following exception - ***ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package***.

If i remove `import mypackage` from the script everything is going fluently. Of course in python console this script is working fine and all imports resolved correctly.
One extra thing to mention, my Visual Studio project is located at C:\users\Me\MyDocuments......\PythonDLRTest and of course running from there. Importing packages located as shown at script and i'm guessing the problem that i'm facing is some how related to those paths.

May be someone can explain what i'm doing wrong and how this import problem can be resolved. Also it will be very interesting to understand a low level differences between python and ironpython and why the import resolution should be different.

Comment: Does mypackage have any relative imports in it?

Comment: Yes. It has imports, also the packages imported by it has imports and so on. Module of "mypackage" is a regular python module which is using modules/packages implemented by other developers.

Comment: Nothing springs to mind. Could you put together a self-contained, minimal reproduction and post an issue at https://ironpython.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create ?

Comment: Did someone find a solution for this??